# How to get id of element which called function

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i am newbie in jquery...

i have few anchor link in my project...

```
<a href="#" id="1" class="delete" onclick="dele()"> Remove1 </a>
<a href="#" id="2" class="delete" onclick="dele()"> Remove2 </a>
<a href="#" id="3" class="delete" onclick="dele()"> Remove3 </a>
<a href="#" id="4" class="delete" onclick="dele()"> Remove4 </a>

function dele()
    {
        fid= //here i want id of that element which called it
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            data : {delet:'delet',fid:fid},
            type : 'POST',
            success : function(data)
            {
                $("#showform").html(data);
                    alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

for example

if i click on **Remove1** then i want it's **id** say **1**,

if i click on **Remove2** then i want it's **id** say **2** and so on...

i tried to do this by **$(".delete").click()** but i can't use it because it's causing problem for my project...

here id i am generating through database...

can you suggest how can i get id???

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="#" id="1" class="delete" onclick="dele(this.id)"> Remove1 </a>
```

Script

```
function dele(id)
    {
        fid= id //here your id
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            data : {delet:'delet',fid:fid},
            type : 'POST',
            success : function(data)
            {
                $("#showform").html(data);
                    alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b9wKz/)

Answer (score 1):

Seen as you're using jQuery for your logic, why not use it to bind events and separate JS from the HTML entirely? Try this:

```
<a href="#" id="1" class="delete"> Remove1 </a>
<a href="#" id="2" class="delete"> Remove2 </a>
<a href="#" id="3" class="delete"> Remove3 </a>
<a href="#" id="4" class="delete"> Remove4 </a>
```

```js
$('.delete').click(function() {
    fid = this.id; // this = the element which was clicked on
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax.php',
        data : { delet: 'delet', fid: fid },
        type : 'POST',
        success : function(data) {
            $("#showform").html(data);
                alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

---

> i can't use $(".delete").click()... bcz it's affecting my functionality when i get back response from php file.. i was using this same but after i seen that my functionality is not working if i am using this way

If you are appending the `.delete` elements after the DOM has loaded, you need to amend the above to use a delegated selector:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
   // rest of the code...
});
```

Comment: i mentioned in my question that i can't use $(".delete").click()... bcz it's affecting my functionality when i get back response from php file.. i was using this same but after i seen that my functionality is not working if i am using this way

Comment: That sounds like you need a delegated event handler: `$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
function dele()
{
    var fid= $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax.php',
        data : {delet:'delet',fid:fid},
        type : 'POST',
        success : function(data)
        {
            $("#showform").html(data);
                alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Or even you can send the id directly form the caller function like

```
<a href="#" id="4" class="delete" onclick="dele(this.id)"> Remove4 </a>
```

Comment: Would `this` know the element in this case?

Comment: `this` will represents the current clicked element instance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <a href="#" id="1" class="delete" onclick="dele(this)"> Remove1 </a>
 <a href="#" id="2" class="delete" onclick="dele(this)"> Remove2 </a>
 <a href="#" id="3" class="delete" onclick="dele(this)"> Remove3 </a>
 <a href="#" id="4" class="delete" onclick="dele(this)"> Remove4 </a>


function dele(element)
{
    fid= element.id;
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax.php',
        data : {delet:'delet',fid:fid},
        type : 'POST',
        success : function(data)
        {
            $("#showform").html(data);
                alert(data);
        }
    });
 }
```

instead of only id if u pass the element u can get some other properties of the element also.